# c# mono get cpu usage of threads

Tags: c#, linux, process, mono, cpu-usage

How can i get the cpuload of running-threads of my application.
My application runs on linux, mac NOT windows.

I update mono to version 3.0.2. 
Now i can get the correct thread-count of "`Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads`" but no `ProcessThread` object is available to read the "`TotalProcessorTime`"

What can i do to calculate the cpu-usage/threads of my running application?

Can i get the linux-process-id of my running thread? If i can, i can read the proc directory structure but i can't find any way.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the `Process.Threads` property is only [partially implemented at the moment](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/ef6313d9c43e75db627984bf28206e099086de3b):

```csharp
// This'll return a correctly-sized array of empty ProcessThreads for now.
int error;
return new ProcessThreadCollection(new ProcessThread[GetProcessData (pid, 0, out error)]);
```

Not sure what trouble you have run into getting the process id, this code [seems to work](http://ideone.com/tqRTHU) for me:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int pid = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        DirectoryInfo taskDir = new DirectoryInfo(String.Format("/proc/{0}/task", pid));
        foreach(DirectoryInfo threadDir in taskDir.GetDirectories())
        {
            int tid = Int32.Parse(threadDir.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(tid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is correct but i can't reference the managed-thread-id to the linux-thread-id.

Comment: [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between managed and unmanaged threads. Specifically, a sophisticated host can use the CLR Hosting API to schedule many managed threads against the same operating system thread, or to move a managed thread between different operating system threads." Mono might not currently be doing that, but I wouldn't depend on it.